# Ext JS Component similar to Flex View Stack

Tags: extjs4.1

Is there any component in Ext JS 4 similar to Flex view Stack?
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=navigators_3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
layout: 'card'
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I did the same. but couldn't close the question as I had to wait for 8 hours before i close or answer my own question. Thanks.